# New app which Use AndroidX artifacts crash

Tags: android, androidx

When creating new app and checking the `Use Android X artifacts` without modifying anything the app crash bout on my phone and the emulator.

I have asked my friend to repeat method of creating the app and every thing work in his phone.

It is my first time using Android X, Am I doing something wrong? I am running Android Studio 3.3.0.20 in snap (Linux).

```
2019-02-08 17:54:44.477 5487-5487/worshifter.com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: worshifter.com.myapplication, PID: 5487
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{worshifter.com.myapplication/worshifter.com.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at worshifter.com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/constraintlayout/widget/R$styleable;
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:590)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:567)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at worshifter.com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-02-08 17:54:44.478 5487-5487/worshifter.com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/worshifter.com.myapplication-gnuqp7fLCQHjhJ5ZKGKRAQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/worshifter.com.myapplication-gnuqp7fLCQHjhJ5ZKGKRAQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 28 more
```

[image]

**Edit** found out that when removing `android.enableJetifier=true` the app works.

Comment: "Failed resolution of: Landroidx/constraintlayout/widget/R$styleable", I am not sure if you found a bug of AndroidX...

Comment: you should follow checklist: 1. Clean-build 2.Check if `android.useAndroidX=true \n
android.enableJetifier=true` is there in gradle.properties file. 3. Check if instant-run is on, disable it for sometime. 4. You will have your app working.

Comment: Hy @GenoChen I have add Edit in the end of the post may be it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. 
As you see it show in logs: `Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)`

You should go to project level `build.gradle` and update ConstraintLayout to the latest version (and also the good idea update all other dependencies from beta versions):

Default dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
```

Actual version:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

Also I created bugreport about this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122892917

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as simple as upgrading the libraries to their latest version in the `build.gradle` file.

Hint: Use the Android Studio's linting feature to update the libraries to their latest version (<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

I got same error,

My release apk can install to Emulator, Device,

But it crashed.

I check `build.gradle` file, updated to library to latest version.

Also remove deprecated library, error library, as image in below.

[image]

Then, my release apk never got crash when start application as before.